# FileHandler in config file logging rare behabior

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

I have a logging config file:

**logger_config.yml**

```
version: 1
formatters:
  simple:
    format: '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: simple
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
  file:
    class: logging.FileHandler
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: simple
    filename: train.log
loggers:
  trainLogger:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [console]
    propagate: 1
root:
  level: DEBUG
  handlers: [console]
  propagate: 1
```

And a simple script:

**test.py**

```
import logging
import logging.config
import yaml


with open('logging_config.yml', 'rt') as f:
    config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())

logging.config.dictConfig(config)

# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# 'application' code
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warn('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')
```

When I run `test.py` it's suppose that the script will just log in console since the `handler` for `root` is `console` but an empty train.log is also created. Why this append?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a `fileHandler` when loading your logger instance, even though you are only *using* the `consoleHandler`. If you just run the following in the shell:

```
import logging
fh = logging.FileHandler("mylogger.txt")
quit()
```

You'll see that "mylogger.txt" is created. This is because behind the scenes, the handler creates the file upon `__init__`, not at the time of use. It's better design that way, as you might *use* that handler multiple times, possibly at the same time, and you don't want to check for the existence of a file every time, as that would be slow and you could introduce a race condition upon trying to create the file